# Find longest path between root node and any child

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I have an array of elements, some of whom have children, who have children in turn and so on. I know the direct children of each element, and have a list of all descendents for each element.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)descendents:(Element *)e {

    NSMutableArray * descendents = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString * uID in e.children){
        [descendents addObject:uID];
        Element * k = elements[uID][@"element"];
        [descendents addObjectsFromArray:[self descendents:k]];
    }
    return descendents;
}
```

I can determine the root element by comparing the total number of descendents for each element. I can find the shortest route between the root and any given element given this:

```
-(int)find:(NSString *)uniqueID forElement:(Element *)e {

    int distance = 0;
    if ([e.children containsObject:uniqueID]){ //immediate child

        distance ++; //increment distance
        return distance; //return

    } else if ([e.descendents containsObject:uniqueID]){ //grand child etc

        distance ++;
        for (NSString * uID in e.children){
            Element * k = elements[uID][@"element"];
            distance += [self find:uniqueID forElement:k];
            return distance;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is find the *longest* distance between an element and the root. I'm thinking about going back up the tree from elements with zero children or adding an array of distances between elements in the mapping function. Struggling as to the cleanest approach - any ideas?

**EDIT:**
solution based on user3290797's answer below, tracking reference to max number of *parents*:

```
-(int)parentHeight:(NSString *)uID {

    int maxHeight = 0;
    Element * e = elements[uID][@"element"];
    for (NSString * parentID in e.parents){
        int height = [self parentHeight:parentID];
        maxHeight = (height > maxHeight) ? height : maxHeight;
    }
    return maxHeight + 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longest distance between an element and the root is called the height (or depth) of the tree.

One way to find it is to recursively traverse the tree and calculate the height of every node as the maximum of its children's heights plus one.

In pseudocode:

```
function height(node) {
    maxChildHeight = 0
    for(child in node.children) {
        h = height(child)
        if(h > maxChildHeight) {
            maxChildHeight = h
        }
    }
    return maxChildHeight + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, does this  work even with multiple paths to a single node, some of which are longer than others?

Comment: It works as long as the graph doesn't contain cycles.

Comment: No cycles! Ok, I'll try the code in the morning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or, I should say, no cycles looping back to the root. Paths can split and converge again later.

Comment: Since the graph in your case is directed, splitting and converging is not a cycle. A cycle is a path that returns to its original node (not necessarily the root). For example, B is a child of A, C is a child of B, A is a child of C.

Comment: Ok great, I block that from happening. Everything is directed to the bottom of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

If not a lot of nodes, calculate each distance and assign an ID for each , then check the longest of them , this is slow but works hahaha

Comment: It's the distance calculation that I'm stuck on - comparing distances against an if is fine.

Comment: Oh sorry ok I think on it I like the questions, maybe tomorrow I post if someone don't do it before